# RavenDb initialize not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

Here is my enviorment:
* Windows 7
* Installed RavenDb.Embedded with NuGet which ended up pulling version 2.0.2230
* IIS 7
* VS2012 Express
* MVC 4
* Running in Debug mode.

Web.config sections...

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="RavenDb" connectionString="DataDir = ~\RavenData" />  
</connectionStrings>  
<appSettings>  
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />  
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />     
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />   
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />  
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />  
  <add key="RavenDb/Port" value="8081" />  
  <add key="RavenDb/DataDir" value="~\RavenData" />  
  <add key="RavenDb/AnonymosAccess" value="Get" />  
</appSettings>
```

The code in the application start is....

```
// Test getting create connection to new ravenDB
IDocumentStore test = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};
test.Initialize();

//never get to this line
int x = 12;
```

The raven files do get created.   However the code never reaches x = 12.   It looks to be caught in an infinite loop.   I never get an error message.

Comment: There is a typo in 
<add key="RavenDb/AnonymosAccess" value="Get" />
should be
<add key="RavenDb/AnonymousAccess" value="Get" />

Also is port 8081 used by something else maybe?

Comment: I made the change that you pointed out.   It has not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with your configuration. If you want to see the code it is here.

https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/MvcRavenDbEmbedded

I'll post the most important part.

```
namespace EmbeddedRavenSite
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public IDocumentStore DocumentStore;

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            DocumentStore = RavenConfig.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

and The RavenConfig class:

```
namespace EmbeddedRavenSite.App_Start
{
    public static class RavenConfig
    {
        public static IDocumentStore Init()
        {
            return new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            }.Initialize();

        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. The code I have included has NuGet package restore, so you should be able to build and start working right away. Good Luck :)